# EAS Build => Task :app:processReleaseMainManifest FAILED

Tags: android, expo, eas

I'm trying to build an apk file via expo but without success.

Does anyone have any ideas?

```
[stderr] 

* What went wrong:

[stderr] 

A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:processReleaseMainManifest' (type 'ProcessApplicationManifest').

[stderr] 

  - In plugin 'com.android.internal.version-check' type 'com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessApplicationManifest' property 'mainManifest' specifies file '/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml' which doesn't exist.

[stderr] 

    Reason: An input file was expected to be present but it doesn't exist.
```